# How to know which modified files on node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, npm, serverless-framework, console.log

I'm using the serverless framework and install them through npm. I have also modified some file in the node_modules folder by add `console.log` to debugging, but I can't remember which file was changed.

What should I do next? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why cant you use git or some other version control to trace the code changes.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you trying to revert these changes?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to revert the change, and reformat the console.log format like log4j in java also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git, you can track all changes by it. In that case, make sure that the .gitignore file doesn't include the node_modules folder(Dont forgot to add it back if you gonna remove it).

Otherwise, If you are using the Visual Code, you can right-click on the node_modules folder, and then choose to Find In Folder and then search console.log for example. If you are using the other IDE, please search the same functionality for you're IDE.